# recipe for target failed for no apparent reason

Tags: linker, cmake, makefile

I have a problem with one of my projects that I just cannot figure out. I have some code, which I have managed to compile and link on my Ubuntu laptop & desktop, one of my colleagues also managed to install it on his laptop, but now another colleague tries to compile it and he keeps running into "recipe for target '' failed". The problem is that this is the ONLY message that is being shown. From other sources I have found that this is probably an underlying program that is failing, but I have no clue what it could be or how to further debug it. Any ideas are very welcome. The complete make log:

```
[  2%] Performing update step for 'MIPS_RELEASE'
HEAD is now at 8a3ade7... dataFormatStreamReader didn't stop at the end of the stream
[  4%] Performing configure step for 'MIPS_RELEASE'
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
--   program_options
--   serialization
--   unit_test_framework
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/MIPS_RELEASE-prefix/src/MIPS_RELEASE-build
[  7%] Performing build step for 'MIPS_RELEASE'
[100%] Built target mips
[  9%] Performing install step for 'MIPS_RELEASE'
[100%] Built target mips
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/lib/libmips.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/mips.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/weightedVariable.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/sum.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/count.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/mean.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/variance.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/histogram.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/compositeStatistic.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/compositeStatistic.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/sumSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/countSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/meanSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/varianceSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/histogramSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/compositeStatisticSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/statistics/concepts/statistic.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/rootedPointerTree.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/rootedPointerTree.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/rootedPointerTreeSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/defaultNodeIterator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/defaultNodeIterator.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/core/tree/rootedTreeTraits.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/optionClass.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/optionClass.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/optionClassSerialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/dataFormatStreamReader.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/dataFormatStreamReader.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/logger.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/logManager.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/sink.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/storeByPointer.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/storeByValue.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/storeBySmartPointer.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/storeByInheritance.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/wrapPointer.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/sequentialDatabaseWrapper.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/sequentialDatabaseWrapper.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/sequentialDatabaseIterator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/concepts/storagePolicy.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/utilities/concepts/dataFormatConcept.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/namespace.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/concepts/attributeExtractor.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/attributeType.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/concepts/modelClassifier.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/classifier.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/concepts/modelPrinter.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/modelPrinter.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/test.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/modelPrinter.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/classifier.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/defaultLearner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/defaultTree.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/serialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/splittingCriterium.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/defaultSplittingCriterium.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/defaultSplittingCriterium.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/noChangeDBWrapper.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/heuristic.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/varianceReduction.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/informationgain.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/whitneymann.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/decisionTree.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/nodeInfo.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/nodeData.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/testInfo.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/alwaysTrueExtraTest.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/queryEngine.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/queryEngine.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/treePrinter.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/treePrinter.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/detail/heuristicDecider.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/exampleGenerator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/splitExampleGenerator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/splitExampleGenerator.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/testGenerator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/removeUsedTestGenerator.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/removeUsedTestGenerator.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/depthFirstDecisionTreeLearner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/depthFirstDecisionTreeLearner.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/concepts/prePruner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/pruneResult.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/noActionPruner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/depthPruner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/fTestPruner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionTree/minimumLeafSizePruner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/defaultForest.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/depthFirstForestLearner.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/classifier.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/modelPrinter.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/decisionForest.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/serialization.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/probabilisticForest.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/probabilisticSplittingCriterium.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/probabilisticSplittingCriterium.hxx
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/randomFractionForest.hpp
-- Up-to-date: /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include/mips/prediction/decisionForest/randomFraction.hpp
[ 11%] Completed 'MIPS_RELEASE'
[ 19%] Built target MIPS_RELEASE
[ 64%] Built target adalab
[ 64%] Built target export-TEST_CONT_NETWORK
[ 64%] Built target export-TEST_HG_NETWORK
[ 64%] Built target export-TEST_HG_NETWORK2
[ 64%] Built target export-TEST_HG_NETWORK3
[ 66%] Built target testNetwork
[ 69%] Built target testVertex
[ 69%] Built target export-SAMPLING_NETWORK
[ 71%] Built target test_experimentalspacesampling
[ 73%] Built target test_experiments
[ 73%] Built target export-TEST_EXPERIMENT
[ 73%] Built target export-TEST_NETWORK
[ 73%] Built target export-TEST_NETWORK2
[ 73%] Built target export-TEST_NETWORKCONT
[ 76%] Built target testSimulator
[ 76%] Built target export-MY_NETWORK
[ 78%] Built target testExperimentSelector
[ 80%] Built target testSigmoid
[ 83%] Built target testSimulated
[ 85%] Built target testUnitStep
[ 88%] Building CXX object src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o
src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1031: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/all' failed
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

**EDIT**: Running make with -d option (only copied last lines related to testGeneralFunctions):

```
Pruning file 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/flags.make'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o'.
    Must remake target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o'.
Putting child 0x22042e0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 5337 on the chain.
Live child 0x22042e0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 5337 
[ 88%] Reaping winning child 0x22042e0 PID 5337 
Live child 0x22042e0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 5338 
Building CXX object src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o
Reaping winning child 0x22042e0 PID 5338 
Live child 0x22042e0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 5340 
Reaping losing child 0x22042e0 PID 5340 
src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o' failed
Removing child 0x22042e0 PID 5340 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x14b8640 PID 5336 
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1031: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/all' failed
Removing child 0x14b8640 PID 5336 from chain.
Reaping losing child 0x10a9940 PID 5094 
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
Removing child 0x10a9940 PID 5094 from chain.
```

**EDIT2:**

```
src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/build.make:54
```

corresponds to:

```
  $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_report /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/CMakeFiles $(CMAKE_PROGRESS_1)
```

**EDIT3:** 
Last lines of running make with verbose:

```
 make[2]: Entering directory '/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab'
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/CMakeFiles 31
    Putting child 0x1d014c0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 11603 on the chain.
    Live child 0x1d014c0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 11603 
    [ 88%] Reaping winning child 0x1d014c0 PID 11603 
    Live child 0x1d014c0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 11604 
    Building CXX object src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o
    Reaping winning child 0x1d014c0 PID 11604 
    cd /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/src/general/test && /usr/bin/c++    -std=c++0x -lstdc++ -lm -I/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab -I/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/mips_release/local/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -I/usr/share/R/include -I/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include -I/home/daniel/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/include -I/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/inspector -I/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/data    -o CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o -c /home/daniel/repo/AdaLab/src/general/test/testGeneralFunctions.cpp
    Live child 0x1d014c0 (src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o) PID 11606 
    Reaping losing child 0x1d014c0 PID 11606 
    src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/testGeneralFunctions.cpp.o' failed
    Removing child 0x1d014c0 PID 11606 from chain.
    make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab'
    Reaping losing child 0x1e521d0 PID 11602 
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1031: recipe for target 'src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/all' failed
    Removing child 0x1e521d0 PID 11602 from chain.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/daniel/repo/AdaLab'
    Reaping losing child 0xd9b960 PID 11242 
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'all' failed
    Removing child 0xd9b960 PID 11242 from chain.
```

Don't really see that much more in there!

Comment: Seeing the output of a program, but not its source, needs some first class crystal balling to debug. And no, I don't think dumping the whole CMakeLists.txt / source tree on us will help either.

Comment: Run make with debugging on (however cmake wants you to do that) so you can see the actual command that is failing. Alternatively, show us the recipe at `src/general/test/CMakeFiles/testGeneralFunctions.dir/build.make:54` so we can see the command that way (though the former is better).

Comment: What more information would you need? I don't believe the actual source code will help, but I can include generated makefiles or whatever is necessary.

Comment: @etan, I also ran make with option -d. I did not get any wiser from the output. I'll add the last lines of the log.

Comment: We need the command that is being run the `-d` output doesn't include that.

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and post the failing command and the ensuing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested: the real problem was masked due to the fact that the logs did not include stderr, once I got this info it was fixed very quickly. (The logs were mailed to me as my colleague works abroad)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Unix Makefiles you can set the environment variable VERBOSE to see exactly what commands are being run, like this

```
cmake ..
VERBOSE=1 make
```